# WCF Service Invocation Error - Error while receiving HTTP response

Tags: c#, wcf, http, exception, request

I'm almost finished with writing my service, and I've spend the past few hours testing. However, no matter how hard I try, I get an error with one specific service's one specific method ([code visible here](https://gist.github.com/fonix232/8026484))

Everything works fine, except for the Get() and GetAll() methods of Cinema.Server.ShowController. As you can see from the code, Show is a complex object, and I require its transfer, the architecture cannot change.

Any time I invoke these two functions, if there's a database entry for any Show, it will throw the following error message:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   `http://localhost:8090/ShowService`. This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due
>   to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due
>   to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

(Full message with stack trace available [here](http://pastebin.com/yyvJE5gZ))

As there is no error report from WCF apart from this (and this exception is thrown on client-side), I do not know what the problem is. Could someone enlighten me please?

**UPDATE**

So after some SvcTracing, here is the actual exception:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:GetAllResult. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Show_B50FB72FE59AC01FA537205B27B30F94605CB1F39BB27C2F1BBB00EF9A720361'
>   with data contract name
>   'Show_B50FB72FE59AC01FA537205B27B30F94605CB1F39BB27C2F1BBB00EF9A720361:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the client's config file:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Logger.xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

  </system.diagnostics>
```

Run the client a few times getting the error, and confirm that there is a logging.xml file in the exe's folder.

Download the Windows SDK for your OS, and run SvcTraceViewer, pointing it at the xml file. If this doesn't help, put the XML in the server's config and repeat.

It's not guaranteed to give the answer, but can help tremendously!

One pitfall I came across with complex structures in WCF is circular references: an onject contains a list of children; each child contains a reference (serialised as a copy) of its parent. The serialised copy of the parent contains a list of children etc etc.

Cheers -

Comment: My "client" is a website, using the code from above from a shared library. Would adding it to the library's config help?
Also, I double checked, and there is no circular reference: Show refers to a Movie, a Room, a List of Seats, and a List of Bookings. Each Booking then refers to a Ticket, and it ends here (though each ticket contains indirect, manual reference to the Seat, by its row and column number).

Comment: Add it to the Web.Config of the web site. If the WCF Service hosted in the same web site?

Comment: No. As I said, the WCF services (and clients) are all part of a shared library, containing the code from above (all, Shared, Server and Client cs files are part of the Cinema.dll project). The servers and clients use an instance of the Server/ClientReference class, and use those to communicate.

Comment: OK. Add the XML to the Web.Config file of the site and see what the SvcTraceViewer says.

Comment: Got the reports and it turns out, the serverside does throw an error, and it gets caught, but for some reason, not logged. It is a SerializationException, but unfortunately the log does not contain further details. I'll update the question with the exception message.

Comment: I've added the exception to the question, and also tried to solve it using the KnownType attribute, without luck. It is still the same exception, dying on Serialization.

Comment: Have you put the [DataContract] attribute on all the classes that are being returned?#

Comment: Yes I did. As it turns out, Robert on top was right, it had to do with the POCO types that EF returned. After switching to eager loading, all the problems were solved.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Entity Framework inside your WCF service, and you are returning the entity retrieved from the database.  EF dynamically creates a proxy subclass of your class.  WCF doesn't know how to handle the proxy subclass.

This article has more detials:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457(v=vs.100).aspx

> The POCO proxy type cannot be directly serialized or deserialized by
>   the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), because the
>   DataContractSerializer serialization engine can only serialize and
>   deserialize known types. The proxy type is not a known type. For more
>   information, see the Serializing POCO Proxies section in the Working
>   with POCO Entities topic. To serialize POCO proxies as POCO entities,
>   use the ProxyDataContractResolver class to map proxy types to POCO
>   types during serialization.

For some reason MS gives a ProxyDataContractResolver, but not an attribute to apply the resolver.  The article describes implementing a ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute and how to apply it to operations.

**Update:**

There is a related issue with returning EF objects directly through WCF when dealing with circular references.  Say class A has a many to one relationship with class B.  A has a navigation property to B, and B has a collection of A.  This can be handled by marking the DataContract with the attribute [DataContract(IsReference=true)], but if you're passing EF objects back you may not want to add DataContract and DataMember to each class in the model.  Instead, The DataContractSerializer can handle this for you by setting the preserveObjectReferences to true.  Sowmy Srinivasan has an excellent article describing how to do this: [Preserving Object Reference in WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx)

Combining the two aproaches of using the ProxyDataContractResolver and the preserveObjectReferences = true, I came up with these classes:

```
public class ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
    : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(
      OperationDescription operationDescription)
        : base(operationDescription) { }
    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(
      Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return CreateDataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    private static XmlObjectSerializer CreateDataContractSerializer(
      Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return CreateDataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(
      Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns,
      IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes,
            0x7FFF /*maxItemsInObjectGraph*/,
            false/*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/,
            true/*preserveObjectReferences*/,
            null/*dataContractSurrogate*/,
            new ProxyDataContractResolver());
    }
}

public class ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractFormatAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation proxy)
    {
        IOperationBehavior innerBehavior = new ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description);
        innerBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(description, proxy);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        IOperationBehavior innerBehavior = new ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description);
        innerBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(description, dispatch);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription description)
    {
    }
}
```

Then for each operation, I just apply [ReferencePreservingProxyDataContractFormatAttribute]

Comment: Tried to apply it, it f*cked up some of my code. Now none of the List<>s have functions such as "Except", "Union", etc., and I cannot bring them back at all.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the using directive for LINQ.  Check if you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: It was the first thing I checked, and while it wasn't there, adding did not solve the problem, hence my comment.

Comment: The exact error is: Error 23 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cinema.Shared.Booking>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Updated the gist with my latest changes. I know it's not much, as I had to revert many trials, that ended up with the same result. You can see that Linq is used, yet it refuses to compile.

Comment: Hmmm the only thing that should have changed in your service class is the addition of the [ApplyDataContractResolver] to the Get() and GetAll() methods.  My using section for my service has the following:
'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;'

Comment: No, I had to add an EDMX file, that made me modify most of the code (rewriting everything as it added every class definition from Cinema.Shared to Cinema namespace, but not the actual classes, making it fail on build).

Comment: Found the problem. As soon as I have an EDMX file added to the project of the shared library, the List part I mentioned simply fails. As soon as the file is gone, it is working.

Comment: Strange.  Not sure why, but I'm glad you are back to solving your original problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43457/discussion-between-fonix232-and-robert-graves)

Comment: I think I found the actual problem - it is doing lazy loading instead of eager loading. By switching to eager, it should load everything, every sub-reference (that is manually defined of course), and would not use proxies. Of course for this I have to modify all the classes that reference other objects. But question is, how can I go two levels deep with Include?

Answer (score 1):

I think this part of your error:

> 'Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Show_B50FB72FE59AC01FA537205B27B30F94605CB1F39BB27C2F1BBB00EF9A720361'
>   with data contract name
>   'Show_B50FB72FE59AC01FA537205B27B30F94605CB1F39BB27C2F1BBB00EF9A720361:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected.

may be addressed by setting `ProxyCreationEnabled` to false on your context, like this:

```
cx = new CinemaContext();
cx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

There may certainly be more to it than that, but that may help clarify the actual problem.

Then, you may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718153/circular-reference-error-when-serializing-objects-in-asp-net-web-api) post which talks about resolving circular references by using DataContract/DataMember.  I added an answer there that shows you how to do it in a separate file.  See if that helps you out.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already solved the problem by disabling lazy loading on the class Show. 

The issue was that if lazy loading is enabled, the custom class-based properties of the specific object are not loaded until requested, and WPF does not like proxying around. Without lazy loading, the whole object with all references is pulled from the database, and recreated before sending it to the client.

Comment: Cool. May I suggest you answer your own question with this information? This will help others who are searching for solutions to similar problems jump straight to the answer.  If you are able to show the line(s) of code that solved your problem, that would be ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately I've finished the project (school assignment) so long ago that I don't exactly remember HOW I did it, and what lines I used, and I also trashed the source code.