# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, exception

I have refered many questions on this site for the solution to this problem. Everywhere I found that I should add diagnostics to my configuration using code somewhat like follows:

```
<system.diagnostics> 
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "D:\SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

So I have added the above code to my `app.config` file. I got `SdrConfigExample.e2e` in `D:` drive. I opened it using Trace Viewer but I get the same information that was returned to me by Visual Studio that An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host.

I have uploaded `SdrConfigExample.e2e` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2XAE1EBI6rZm12SnU2enFOVUk/edit?usp=sharing

**Update as requested by L.B.**

I am trying to get all the patients from my database.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Lab_Lite_Service 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatients()
    {
        using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
        {
            return db.Patients;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need anything else please specify. I will update.

**Update 2 as suggested by Robert Graves:**

I have moved the diagnostics section mentioned above in my code to Web.Config file of WCF Project and there I get a warning saying that **Configuration Evaluation Context not found.** Below that I find no matching service tag was found. But I have checked my web.config file and found that all the tags have their matching end-tag.

Here is my Web.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Lab_Lite_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Lab_Lite_Models.csdl|res://*/Lab_Lite_Models.ssdl|res://*/Lab_Lite_Models.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=VISHAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Lab_Lite_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <!-- Delete From & To Bookmarks-->
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "D:\SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I get an error mentioned in the title.

Comment: So, what should it mean to us? Server hasn't liked something and closed the connection. What are you trying to do? where is your code? Do we have to browse your profile and see what you have asked before and post an answer based on assumptions?

Comment: OK I will update my question with code in a moment.

Comment: I think you've added the trace information to your WPF client.  Instead add this configuration to the service.

Comment: [This](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) may help to ask a good question

Comment: @RobertGraves I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Lab_Lite_Service 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatients()
    {
        using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
        {
            // note the call of .ToList()
            // you need to materialize the enumerable that is returned, because it's not serializable
            return db.Patients.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your definition of Patient? What happens if you "return new List<Patient>();" instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your trace listener is failing, but the most common problem I've seen when combining EF and WCF is that WCF fails to serialize EF properly because EF generates proxy classes.  Unfortunately WCF just closes the connection and doesn't generate an easily caught exception on the server side.  You can find more detail in this answer:

[WCF Service Invocation Error - Error while receiving HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664851/wcf-service-invocation-error-error-while-receiving-http-response/20667322#20667322)